# Extending the Javascript prototype for all items of a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype-programming

What is the best way to extend the Javascript prototype for all items of a certain class?
I want all textboxes (input) of a certain class to have

```
function OnValueChange()
{
// Wow!
}
```

This way I can add `onblur="OnValueChange"` to my input.

I can do it on an individual object by modify the prototype, but I am wondering if there a way to it for all items of a certain class or other distinguishing attribute.

I have access to jquery in my project

Comment: I'm assuming that just `$('input.myclass').blur(OnValueChange)` won't do what you're looking for?

Comment: What you are talking about is event handling, not prototype inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to jQuery then just use :

```
$(".inputClassNameHere").live("blur", function(){OnValueChange();});
```

This way all current and future inputs with class inputClassNameHere will call OnValueChange when the blur event is triggered.